# Ruby on Rails error message is very long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I purposely made a mistake in my migration file to show the kind of error i get.

```
== 20150321034322 AlterUsers: migrating =======================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
   -> 0.0023s
-- add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, {:limit=>25, :after=>"email"})
   -> 0.0198s
-- change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, {:limit=>100})
   -> 0.0162s
-- rename_column("admin_users", "broken", "hashed_password")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

No such column: admin_users.broken/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:483:in `column_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:759:in `rename_column_sql'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:521:in `rename_column'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Users/my/Desktop/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150321034322_alter_users.rb:6:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:609:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1043:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Shouldn't my error message look like this instead?

```
== 20150321034322 AlterUsers: migrating =======================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
   -> 0.0023s
-- add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, {:limit=>25, :after=>"email"})
   -> 0.0198s
-- change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, {:limit=>100})
   -> 0.0162s
-- rename_column("admin_users", "broken", "hashed_password")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

No such column: admin_users.broken/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:483:in `column_for'
```

It is really depressing to see that long error message lol. I have a feeling maybe i did not install rails correctly. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is called a [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).  For all but the simplest of errors, it can be used to track down just where the issue is.  There's nothing wrong with your installation, this is useful information!

As you can see, in the full error, about 8 lines in, it tells you your file, and what line it was on.

> /Users/my/Desktop/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150321034322_alter_users.rb:6:in `up'

If the error wasn't on purpose, you'd be grateful for that little bit of information to help you track it down!

Comment: That "8 lines in" line should be the first line.  Is there a gem or something that can trim out the error messages to show only the one line or two referencing the code we wrote?  The rest might be helpful in some case of a source-code bug, but not in every-day use, when the rest is just a distraction and pain to scroll back to "where I was".  One workaround is to hit enter until you have a large blank area in your console, then scroll up a bit, then re-create the error - at which point you can scroll down just a bit and find the one line of the 100 that is actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is saying that your schema for table admin_users has no column named "broken"

`No such column: admin_users.broken`

The long output is just a stack trace of the error and is what normally happens.